# jQuery UI Image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a question about my jQuery UI image slider. I like to add more than two images to change, but I don't know how. What should I change to add more Images to change with the slider? 
And how can I center the image, at this time it is floated left. 
Thank you very much!

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider1").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    step: 1,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.value == 1) {
        $('#flask').attr('src', 'img/tweet1.png');
      } else {
        $('#flask').attr('src', 'img/tweet2.png');
      };
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#slider1 {
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: 15em;
  margin-right: 15em;
  margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img/tweet2.png" height="270" width="600" id="flask" />
<div id="slider1">
```

Comment: your code snippet is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should try to increment the "max" value and then to add as many if statements as images you have. Here is an example:

```
$(function() {
  $("#slider1").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.value == 1) {
        $('#flask').attr('src', 'img/tweet1.png');
      } 
      if (ui.value == 2) {
        $('#flask').attr('src', 'img/tweet2.png');
      };
      if (ui.value == 3) {
        $('#flask').attr('src', 'img/tweet2.png');
      };
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked better! But if I choose the first again in the slider, it does not show it. Do you have an idea why? And do you have an idea how I can center the content/pictures in the slider?

Comment: If you do this, you could remove the IF statements and just use: `$('#flask').attr('src', 'img/tweet' + ui.value + '.png');` Just remember if the user drags it to `0`, it may not show a broken image.

Comment: It is due to the fact that I don't take into account the case when ui.value is equal to 0 (you could simply fix it by setting the "min" value to 1). If all the images are called "tweet + number" the Twisty's solution is better then the mine.

Comment: To center the elements in the slider you coud try to use flex box. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Thank you, it works! :) 
But the flex box option only effects the slider and not the images. I don't know why but I will try more. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped! To solve your issue with the centering i had to know more about the structure of your site. I don't know if you noticed the "perfect centering" paragraph in the previous link.
 If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please consider to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This will require specific naming of your images. If you can get the count of images from a serverside script, this would also be helpful as it could set the max.

```js
$(function() {
  // Set to the number of images you will have
  var myMax = 2;
  $("#slider1").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: myMax,
    step: 1,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      // All images must be named correctly: tweetN.png where N is a number
      // if statement in case you want to use 0 position to start with no image 
      if(ui.value > 0){
        $('#flask').attr('src', 'img/tweet' + ui.value + '.png');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#slider1 {
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: 15em;
  margin-right: 15em;
  margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<img src="img/tweet2.png" height="270" width="600" id="flask" />
<div id="slider1"></div>
```

If the images will have different names, you can also create an array and iterate each postion of the array via Slider.

**Example**

```
$(function() {
  var myImages = [
    "img/tweet1.png",
    "img/tweet2.png",
    "img/logo3.jpg",
    "img/splash4.gif"
  ];
  $("#slider1").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: (myImages.length - 1),
    step: 1,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $('#flask').attr('src', myImages[ui.value]);
    }
  });
});
```

Lots of options. Again, if you have access to Server-side scripting like PHP, you could perform an ajax call and get a list of the current images. This way, you just drop the images into one folder, and the script will just know they are there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it tomorrow :)

Comment: @Nils-HendrikWelk glad it helped. If you think it is the answer, I hope you will mark it as so and upvote it.